# change "PrtSc" button behavior to perform right click

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

Is it possible to change `"PrtSc"` button behavior to perform right click. I am using `Win 7 x64`?

**Update**:
I have tried using `sharpkeys` but there is no key option available for `right click`

[image: Sharpkeys problem]

Comment: Sharpkeys won't work because it only remaps keyboard keys. It's even listed on its homepage: it cannot map to mouse clicks. Use one of the AHK solutions below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use this [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script :

```
PrintScreen:: Click right
```

For more information see this AutoHotkey documentation :

[List of Keys, Mouse Buttons, and Joystick Controls](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
[Click](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm)

Comment: Can you tell me how to set this right click here? thanks

Comment: This information is found in the AutoHotkey documentation. In short: Install AutoHotkey, create a .ahk script-file with the above line, put the script in the Startup program-group so it starts with Windows.

Comment: this is not working for apps like outlook, word, excel etc. Still looking for solution... any help..

Comment: I have awarded the bounty but still some help is required on this :P

Comment: I just tested it for Outlook & Word and it worked with no problem.

Comment: @harrymc Consider adding `*` hotkey modifier to make the script work when shift etc. is held down too. Like: `*PrintScreen:: Click right`

Answer (score 2):

Run this code in the console with administrator rights to change the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> key to the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key:

`reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t REG_BINARY /d 0000000000000000020000005de037e000000000 /f`

and reboot your computer.

To undo these changes use this code:

`reg delete "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /f`

Answer (score 0):

Trying to solve similar problem on my Lenovo ThinkPad p50 with Windows 10 without any luck I've come up with my own software program development.

[ThinkTwice](https://github.com/george-polevoy/thinkpad-kb-fix/releases) is a tiny utility which does just that: fixes the keyboard design mistake made by lenovo manufacturers in Lenovo ThinkPad p50 (and probably some other newer ThinkPad models).

It remaps the <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> button when it's pressed alone to the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> which has the same effect of bringing up current context menu as a right click.

You can download a release or build from sources.